# Stargazer error with polr in R

Tags: r, stargazer

I obtain an error when using `stargazer` in conjunction with `polr` from the `MASS` package in `R`. Here is an example:

```
library(MASS)
library(stargazer)

# Fake data
set.seed(1234)
fake_data <- data.frame(y = as.factor(sample.int(4, 20, replace = TRUE)),
                        x1 = rnorm(20, mean = 1, sd = 1),
                        x2 = rnorm(20, mean = -1, sd = 1))

# Ordered logistic regression
o_log <- MASS::polr(y ~ x1 + x2,
                    data = fake_data,
                    Hess = TRUE, method = "logistic")

summary(o_log)

# Create regression table
stargazer(o_log)
```

I receive the following error message:

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I'm on OS X 10.13, using R 3.4.3, MASS 7.3.47, and stargazer 5.2.

**EDIT:** According to stargazer's vignette, objects from `polr` should be supported.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: The last call, i.e. stargazer(o_log).

Comment: It does seem to be a bug in the stargazer package. I get the same error message when I run it on Windows, and you are correct that the documentation for `stargazer()` indicates that it should work with objects of class `polr`. I don't know enough about the package to suggest a work-around.

Comment: The bug here appears to be stargazer's use of `$call` to determine the object type. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931317/using-stargazer-with-a-list-of-lm-objects-created-by-lapply-ing-over-a-split-dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason but when I change `MASS::polr` into `plor`, the error is removed and it works fine. It seems that it is a bug of package stargazer.

Comment: The `plor` in the suggestion is likely at typo, it should be `polr`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. For some strange reason, this only happens when you call the function using `::` (in your case: `MASS::polr`). It doesn't happen when you first load the package via `library(MASS)` and then call the specific function.

See: [Why do I get different results when using library(MASS) vs. MASS::?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483517/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-using-librarymass-vs-mass)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was because you didn't load the `MASS` library and instead called the function using `::`. MASS library doing some updates on how `summary` works for `polr`, which is being used by stargazer to generate the table. By not loading the library, the update was not happened, hence bringing you some trouble with stargazer.